# Add comment on YouTube for video from iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube-api

How can I programmatically add comments to a YouTube video from an iPhone app? I've searched Google and gone through the YouTube Api but haven't found any help.

Comment: there are a lot of components/modules you will be developing for that, there is no simple answer for that

Comment: i need just a start tried to search on google but did n't found anything related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding comment using Youtube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Adding_a_comment)

Adding a comment in response to a video
To add a comment to a video, send a POST request to the URL identified in the  tag that appears inside the  tag. The actual comment that you are submitting appears as the value of the  tag in the XML that constitutes the body of the POST request.
The sample XML API request below demonstrates how to add a comment to a video.

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <content>This is a crazy video.</content>
</entry>
```

construct that xml and send via POST. Get Developer_key, get the VIDEO_ID of the youtube video.

**Using a developer key:**
A developer key uniquely identifies a product that is submitting an API request. Please visit http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/ to obtain a developer key.

**VideoID** – The YouTube video ID that uniquely identifies the video.
I think videoid for a youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ is NWHfY_lvKIQ

Comment: Do you have one for wikipedia? :))